# Multi project application with different UIs

Tags: .net-core-2.2

I need to develop a multi project application using .net core 2.2
Apart from business logic, I need to implement client UI in a project and Admin UI in another. 
How is it possible to do a think like this? I tried to find some example on this matter with no success.
Any suggestion?

Comment: It is definitly possible. Are you facing a specific problem? Want to do the UIs with Razor, Angular,...?

Comment: I want do do this with razor but I don’t know how. Is there anything that I can read for this? Do you have some suggestions? I’m new with multi projects solutions.

Comment: So your problem is setting up the Visual Studio solution?

Comment: When I create the second project, how can I move or copy the static files and views to the main? Where the static files will be copied and what about the references to the views?

Comment: does this help you a bit further: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I’m talking about two different projects that can be developed from two different teams. First the Admin project developed from one team and second, the front end project developed from another team. During compile time, these two projects must be one. This is where I need help (as a newbie on this). How can I accomplish this during compile time.

Comment: Thank you Monty for your suggestion. I think that this is solving my problem.